# Updated 2 values in 1 column with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is probably super easy but I am not sure how to word it for search purposes. I have a table that goes something likes this:

```
id   month   current
1    may     0
2    june    0
3    july    1
```

Current is set to be a boolean. 1 indicated that it's current. 0s show that it's not and won't be used in code for display purposes. Either way, how can I write an UPDATE sql query to simultaneously set July to "0" and change may to "1" if May is selected? So far I've "concocted" this awfulness:

```
if(isset($_POST["setMonth"])){
   $month = $_POST["monthname"];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
   $query_set_month = "UPDATE months SET current = 0 WHERE month = $current_month AND current = 1"; //this will "unset" my current month...?
   $result_month = mysql_query($query_set_month) or die('Query failed: ' .
                    mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
}
```

Comment: You need two `UPDATE` statements to modify two rows with different values. The "simultaneousliness" is achieved by wrapping the two `UPDATE` statements into a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you need can look like this:

```
$query_set_month = "UPDATE months SET current=IF(month='$current_month', 1, 0)
                    WHERE month='$current_month' OR current=1";
```

Comment: I am not using this right or something... It does exactly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (x CHAR(1),y TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('a',0),('b',1),('c',0);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+---+
| x    | y |
+------+---+
| a    | 0 |
| b    | 1 |
| c    | 0 |
+------+---+

UPDATE my_table
   SET y = 1 XOR y
 WHERE x IN ('b','c');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+---+
| x    | y |
+------+---+
| a    | 0 |
| b    | 0 |
| c    | 1 |
+------+---+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```